# listview gives wrong item on click after filtering

Tags: android, listview, filter, onclick

I have a `listView` with a custom adapter which implements filterable. The filter function works finally perfectly fine, up until I try to open an item within the `listView`. When I try to open my filtered result, it moves me to the wrong activity. I've gone through some different approaches from other posts, one of which (latest attempt) is marked as a comment in my code down below.

What's weird to me is why this problem occurs, since I'm using a simple "if-else" case...

Another post, which I can't find anymore, suggested to use set/get-tag, which I'm not very familiar with. I also suspect the issue might lie within the filter, since the filter doesnt give out the arrayList, but the filtered version of it. However, I couldn't figure that one out, either.

Any help is appreciated!

MainActivity down to its core:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{
    MyAdapter adapter;`

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lw = findViewById(R.id.lw);
        Button notiz = findViewById(R.id.btnNotiz);
        Button merk = findViewById(R.id.btnMerk);
        EditText suche = findViewById(R.id.suchen);

        lw.setLongClickable(true);

        final ArrayList<Objekt> arrayList = new ArrayList();

        arrayList.add(new Objekt("AAA", "AAA-Street"));
        arrayList.add(new Objekt( "BBB","BBB-Street")); // and so on

        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,arrayList);
        suche.addTextChangedListener(this);

        Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<Objekt>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Objekt o1, Objekt o2) {
              return o1.getKuerzel().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getKuerzel());
            }
        });

        lw.setAdapter(adapter);

        lw.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullAdress);
                ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                assert cm != null;
                cm.setText(textView.getText().toString());

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Kopiert!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        lw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selection = arrayList.get(position).getKuerzel();
                //one of the things I've tried: Objekt selection = (Objekt)((MyAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
                if(selection.equals("AAA")){
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AAA.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                } else if(selection.equals("BBB")){
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BBB.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                } //and so on
           }
        });

    }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Objekt> arr, tempArr;
    CustomFilter cs;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Objekt> arr) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arr = arr;
        this.tempArr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arr.get(position);
        //return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_view_layout,parent,false);

        TextView kuerzel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewKuerzel);
        TextView fullAdress = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullAdress);

        kuerzel.setText(arr.get(position).getKuerzel());
        fullAdress.setText(arr.get(position).getFullAdress());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (cs == null){
            cs = new CustomFilter();
        }

    return cs;
    }

    class CustomFilter extends Filter{
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

                ArrayList<Objekt> filters = new ArrayList<Objekt>();

                for (int i = 0; i < tempArr.size(); i++) {
                    if (tempArr.get(i).getKuerzel().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        Objekt objekt = new Objekt(tempArr.get(i).getKuerzel(), tempArr.get(i).getFullAdress());
                        filters.add(objekt);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filters.size();
                results.values = filters;
            }
            else
            {
                results.count = tempArr.size();
                results.values = tempArr;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            arr = (ArrayList<Objekt>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Objekt:

```
public class Objekt {

    String kuerzel;
    String fullAdress;

    public Objekt(String kuerzel, String fullAdress) {
        this.kuerzel = kuerzel;
        this.fullAdress = fullAdress;
    }

    public String getKuerzel() {
        return kuerzel;
    }

    public void setKuerzel(String kuerzel) {
        this.kuerzel = kuerzel;
    }

    public String getFullAdress() {
        return fullAdress;
    }

    public void setFullAdress(String fullAdress) {
        this.fullAdress = fullAdress;
    }
}
```

I haven't quite figured out formatting here, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

After applying the filter in MyAdapter class, the elements in the arr in MyAdapter and arrayList in the MainActivity will be different. for example, if initially your list contains ['AAA','BBB','AAC','CCC','DDD'] then both the list will have same elements:

```
arrayList = ['AAA','BBB','AAC','CCC','DDD'] // in MainActivity
arr = ['AAA','BBB','AAC','CCC','DDD'] // in MyAdapter
```

Now if you apply the filter by typing 'AA', the elements of the arr will be updated but arraylist will remain same.

```
arrayList = ['AAA','BBB','AAC','CCC','DDD'] // in MainActivity
arr = ['AAA','AAC'] // in MyAdapter
```

Now if the user has selected the second element from the list i.e. at index 1. 
In your MainActivity, you have used String selection = `arrayList.get(position).getKuerzel();`

It will return 'BBB' as you are selecting index 1 from the arrayList.

The solution to the problem is to filter arrayList as well in onTextChanged method.

```
 @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        //filter arrayList
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate answer! Since I'm rather new to app programming, I'm not sure how to go on with filtering the arrayList in the onTextChanged method...
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        adapter.getFilter().filter(arrayList.toString());
    }

I'm unsure how to filter the arrayList :thinking: